# Refreshing a Sandbox via the Tooling API - HTTP PATCH

Tags: tooling-api

In a series of questions regarding the Tooling API... one more rofl

I'm trying to refresh a Sandbox via the Tooling API. For that, according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm):

> To refresh a sandbox:
>
> 1. To start a sandbox refresh, edit the SandboxInfo record.
> 2. To find the status of a sandbox after it is enqueued, find the latest SandboxProcess record by querying SandboxProcess for a given
>      SandboxInfoId value. The value of Status indicates the current state
>      of the process.
> 3. When the Status field value is Pending Activation, change the value of the RefreshAction field to either ACTIVATE or DISCARD.

Therefor, I tried to do the following:

1. First get the sandbox Id from Production, via a [query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214793/getting-the-sourceid-of-current-sandboxes-in-the-system/214796?noredirect=1#comment324944_214796).
2. One I had the Id, try to execute a **HTTP PATCH method** (which is available according to the documentation referenced above):

**Endpoint:**

```
/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo/
```

**Payload:**

```
{
  "AutoActivate": true,
  "Id": "0GQ58000000TQacGAG"
}
```

But the response I get is the following:

```
[ { "errorCode" : "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED", "message" : "HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,POST" } ]
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How is the update supposed to be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PATCH methods use the ID in the URL; if you put it in the body, it simply won't work.

Here's how it should look:

```
/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo/0GQ58000000TQacGAG

{
  "AutoActivate": true
}
```

Using the URL you're trying: `/services/data/v42.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo`, you're actually hitting an "insert" URL (you would use this to create a new SandboxInfo).

You can try this out with something like an Account or another type of record to experiment without creating new sandboxes.

Comment: Man, you're guiding me through the whole Tooling API adventure hahaha. Thanks! :)

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano No problem! Always glad to help.

Comment: Update to that answer: you also need to specify the license type in the request body like this: `"LicenseType": "DEVELOPER"`

Comment: If your user doesn't have °Modify All Data" permission it will not work, unfortunately: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SpyaQAC

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala I'm somehow not surprised that this happened. The Tooling API itself requires Modify All Data to do almost anything with it. However, that's definitely a bug, and I'm sure that Salesforce will fix this. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you know how to set apex class id when refreshing? Im trying to add `ApexClassId` in this api, but dont work

Comment: @vctqs1 SandboxInfo can't use ApexClassId on a refresh. Use the [SandboxProcess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxprocess.htm) object instead.